# Rails - How To Check if Defined before adding into new Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with the Amazon Product Advertising API and I'm trimming its responses within my controller to render customized JSON, but its responses change a lot depending on the product category, so I need to write code that can catch all of the ways it changes.  I only need a few pieces of data, so how can I simply check to see if those pieces exist within Amazon's API response before including them in my own custom JSON?

Note:  I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/mhuggins/a2z) to integrate with Amazon's API.  It returns the API responses in its own objects.

```
@results = (Amazon's API response)
@custom_response = []
@results.items.each do |product|
        @new_response = OpenStruct.new(
                        :id => product.asin, 
                        :source => "amazon", 
                        :title => product.title, 
                        :price => @product_price, 
                        :img_small => @images[0], 
                        :img_big => @images[1], 
                        :category =>  product.product_group, 
                        :link => "http://amazon.com/" )
        @custom_response << @new_response
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
@new_response = OpenStruct.new(:source => "amazon", :link => ".....")

@new_response.id = product.asin if product.asin.present? 
@new_response.title = product.title if product.title.present?
other attributes....
```